# Android: Create a swipe gesture event programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gesture

I've been trying to find an answer for this specific case on Google and amazingly couldn't find it anywhere (there's just answers about detecting, not creating, swipes). I want to actually 'run' a simulated swipe from right to left on the screen (doesn't matter where, but ideally from the right edge to the left). I tried something like this, but I get a NPE:

```
final float viewWidth = view.getWidth();
    TouchUtils.drag(null,viewWidth,1f,0f,0f,1);
```

The reason? I need to force a swipe to the next page in an infinite viewpager which has no real reference to the page position (so I can't just use setCurrentItem).

Any ideas?

Comment: "so I can't just use setCurrentItem" -- um, why not call `pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem()+1, true);`? You may think it is "infinite", but `ViewPager` still uses item positions.

Comment: For some reason, doing that causes the entire app to freeze up - and logcat isn't helping...

Comment: Well, `TouchUtils` is for testing, not for production code. While it's at least theoretically possible for you to simulate touch events to your own app, I am unconvinced that it will prove to be a stable and reliable solution to your problem. I recommend that you set some breakpoints and figure out where `setCurrentItem()` is not working for you.

Comment: i want to use test class like instrumentation, Touchutils ..etc for production.. purpose was, to simulate our app from remote.. is it possible to use test class on production... ?

Answer (score 1):

As already said `TouchUtils.drag` uses `Instrumentation` that could be used in `androidTest` only.
I have wrote extension functions that doesn't require `Instrumentation`, so they could be used in release build:

```
fun ViewGroup.performSwipeToLeft(target: View) {
    this.performSwipe(target, distanceX = -this.width * .5f, distanceY = 0f)
}
fun ViewGroup.performSwipeToRight(target: View) {
    this.performSwipe(target, distanceX = +this.width * .5f, distanceY = 0f)
}
fun ViewGroup.performSwipeToTop(target: View) {
    this.performSwipe(target, distanceX = 0f, distanceY = -this.height * .5f)
}
fun ViewGroup.performSwipeToBottom(target: View) {
    this.performSwipe(target, distanceX = 0f, distanceY = +this.width * .5f)
}

fun ViewGroup.performSwipe(target: View, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float) {
    val parentCoords = intArrayOf(0, 0)
    this.getLocationInWindow(parentCoords)

    val childCoords = intArrayOf(0, 0)
    target.getLocationInWindow(childCoords)

    val initGlobalX = childCoords[0].toFloat() + 1f
    val initGlobalY = childCoords[1].toFloat() + 1f

    val initLocalX = (childCoords[0] - parentCoords[0]).toFloat() + 1f
    val initLocalY = (childCoords[1] - parentCoords[1]).toFloat() + 1f

    val downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
    var eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

    this.dispatchTouchEvent(
        MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            initGlobalX,
            initGlobalY,
            0
        ).apply {
            setLocation(initLocalX, initLocalY)
            source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
        }
    )

    val steps = 20
    var i = 0
    while (i in 0..steps) {
        val globalX = initGlobalX + i * distanceX / steps
        val globalY = initGlobalY + i * distanceY / steps
        val localX = initLocalX + i * distanceX / steps
        val localY = initLocalY + i * distanceY / steps
        if (globalX <= 10f || globalY <= 10f) {
            break
        }
        this.dispatchTouchEvent(
            MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime,
                ++eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
                globalX,
                globalY,
                0
            ).apply {
                setLocation(localX, localY)
                source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
            }
        )
        i++
    }

    this.dispatchTouchEvent(
        MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            ++eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
            initGlobalX + i * distanceX,
            initGlobalY + i * distanceY,
            0
        ).apply {
            setLocation(initLocalX + i * distanceX, initLocalY + i * distanceY)
            source = InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN
        }
    )
}
```

To use it you need pass your current page content as an argument, and viewPager as a receiver of this functions:

```
val viewPager = ...
viewPager.performSwipeToLeft(viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.currentItem))
```