# Android trigger right swipe on create method

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hello I am new to android and I stuck in a problem I created a app using android default slider layout ..

I need to trigger event on create method programmatic below is my code where I shown by comment what I exactly need

**This is my main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        //*******THIS IS WHAT I NEED **********************************************************
        // when i swipe this method is called and i need this method to trigger on create method 
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 999;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't explicitly trigger `onCreateView` it's automatically called when Fragment is created. What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: I think you can use [gesture events](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector) and call a method which does whatever you want, not necessary onCreate method.

Comment: @ Umang Burman  i fetch some JSON Aynnc data and display each time on onCreateView  but when app is launched i need to trigger first position in this view

Comment: @Mihai Coman but i don't need to track gesture events  instead i need to trigger right swipe event programmatic

Comment: Why is your Fragment static by the way?

Comment: i used this layout from android default activity ...i don'y know what do mean by static i am new to android devlopment

Comment: Yoy should tell us what you really want to achieve, if you think you need to trigger ``onCreate()`` manually you are trying to make something in the bad way. Why do you think so?

Comment: @Gonzalo when i swipe right setCurrentItem is set to next item () and when this next item is loaded some JSON data is fetched Aysnc and filled in layout and this is working fine but when app starts first SectionsPagerAdapter item is blank and i need to fill json data on initial load

Comment: reason why  I need to force a swipe to the next page in an infinite viewpager which has no real reference to the page position similar to my problem but there is also no solution provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563169/android-create-a-swipe-gesture-event-programmatically)

Comment: @sam999 Why ``position + 1`` instead of ``position``?

Comment: @Gonzalo to go to next item position is equal to current item position so next item will be current + 1

Comment: @sam999 If I've understood, you want to call ``onCreateView()`` from your ``onCreate()`` method (your comment says the oposite but that has no sense). But it shouldn't be necessary, when you set the adapter it should create the first ``fragment``. How do you now it isn't been created?

Comment: @Gonzalo i asked another question because here i am unable to show what i need exactly you can view my problem in detail here  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969292/viewpager-data-not-loading-on-initial-app-load)