# ViewPager not working Tabbed Activity - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone from last three days i am trying to solve small issue but i can't find any solution yet i posted my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969292/viewpager-data-not-loading-on-initial-app-load) please someone with good android experience help me.
Thanks

Comment: i have answer you question the link you given please check

Comment: thanks let me check :)